# Count the maximum number of occurences within any 2 hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `Transactions`:

```
INSERT into Transactions(Timestamp, Transaction)
values(2022-10-10 19:58:08,A)
values(2022-10-19 18:46:05,B)
values(2022-10-19 18:49:05,C)
values(2022-10-19 19:49:20,D) 
values(2022-10-20 18:49:20,E) 
values(2022-10-20 19:20:05,F)
```

Could anyone please help me with how to count the maximum number of transactions within any 2 hours? In this case, the result should be 3. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Range` function with `Window`

```sql
SELECT MAX(count_per_2_hours) AS max_per_2_hours
FROM ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) over(
            ORDER BY TIMESTAMP 
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 2 hour PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
        ) AS count_per_2_hours
    FROM Transactions 
) AS counts_per_2_hours;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C49u7t4-)

| max_per_2_hours |
| --- |
| 3 |

Comment: thank you @Islam Elbanna, but it seems that you misunderstand what I mean. I would like to count in any 2 hour time window, for eg: if there is a transaction at 2022-10-19 18:46:05 and another transaction at 2022-10-19 20:01:00, they should be counted as in the same 2 hour window because they both happen within 2 hours. But with your suggested query, they will belong to different time windows.

Comment: Another problem is that is there is no transaction happen between 2022-10-19 19:00:00 and 2022-10-19 19:59:59, the query will sum up the numbers of transaction in (between 2022-10-19 18:00:00 and 2022-10-19 18:59:59) and (between 2022-10-19 20:00:00 and 2022-10-19 20:59:59) because these hours are next to each other in table `counts_per_hour`.

Comment: could you help me once again with it, please? :(

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I have updated the answer to use a rolling window instead of fixed look back, let me know if it helped!